# Specific amount of training data required for fine-tuning Resnet-50 model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

for decent generalization, how many images per class is needed for fine-tuning the Resnet-50 model for ASL HandSign Classification(24 classes)? I have around 600 images per class and the model is overfitting very badly.

Comment: Why do you think it is overfitting? Could you print a confusion Matrix (preferably with [confusion matrix ordering](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/25008/8820))

Comment: I think that since the problem is interclass-variation problem, it requires more data per class than to normally requires. My opinion is that 600 images per class is just too few for a problem with many target classes. I am fine-tuning the resent-50 model according to the pytorch transfer learning tutorial.

Comment: 24 classes is really not much. You're using a pre-trained resnet, right? So you only adjust the last layers, correct? The pre-trained one is trained on 1000 classes of ImageNet. And the biggest problem I've seen so far has ~20,000 classes. My bachelors thesis had ~380 classes (but way smaller feature space). So: No, 24 classes is not inherently a problem.

Comment: Yes, I changed the fully-connected layer to 24 outputs and fine-tuned the model without freezing any layers. I trained around 3 Epochs and the Trained Acc is around 0.92 but the val Acc is only around 0.30. When I classify the new image with using the trained model, the predicted result is nearly always false and biased towards one class(in my case, it always classify new images as 'C'). For the datasets, here are the samples :  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h9T1bNzlgpEJsDtiTcDJYRN0xprbEQOB/view

Answer (score 3):

I can't give you a number, but a method to find it yourself. The technique is plotting a graph called "**learning curve**" where the x-axis is the number if training samples and the y-axis is the score. You start at 1 training sample and increase to 600. You plot two curves: the training error and the test error. You can then see how much influence more data without any other change will have on the result.

More details and the following image in [my masters thesis, section 2.5.4](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.09725.pdf):

[image]

In this example you can see that having up to 20 training samples each new example is improving the test score a lot (green curve goes down a lot). But after that, throwing just more data at the problem will not help a lot.

The curve will look different in your case, but the principle should be the same.

### Other analysis

Look at chapter 2.5 and 2.6 of my masters thesis. I especially recommend having a look at the confusion matrix and [confusion matrix ordering](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/25008/8820). This will give you an idea which classes are confused. Maybe the classes are just inherently difficult to distinguish? Maybe one can add more features? Maybe there are labeling errors? Have a look at chapter 2.5 for more of those "maybe's"